# Unrecoverable git push?

Tags: git, version-control, github, git-rebase

I'm still trying to understand the ramifications of rebase and rewriting Git history. Imagine a repository R on github with a year's worth of valuable source code history. Let's say it's the only copy on the planet.

Are there things a committer could do, by cloning the repository, making some changes, and pushing them back, that would cause permanent loss in that repository? I don't know, some weird sequence of rebases, deletes, pushes? And if so, are there any such sequences that would be irreversible immediately (rather than taking place a month or so later, after garbage collection)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, non fast-forward pushes are rejected by the server.  However, from the [git-push man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-push), you can find a means to force the server to accept a potentially destructive push operation:

> **-f, --force**
>
> Usually, the command refuses to update a remote ref that is not an ancestor of the local
>   ref used to overwrite it. This flag disables the check. *This can cause the remote
>   repository to lose commits; use it with care.*

As the warning says, this may cause the remote to lose one or more commits.  Specifically, this may happen if the destination branch's commit is not reachable from another branch's HEAD.

For example,  the following scenario may cause the server to lose a commit:

```
git clone ...
edit ...
git add .
git commit --amend -m "These changes overwrite origin/master's HEAD."
git push -f origin master
```

However, if the commit you just tried to overwrite happened to be tagged or accessible from another branch's HEAD, the commit will not be lost.

Comment: So presumably you could overwrite every commit in the entire history using this method. Doesn't this break one of the tenets of version control?

Comment: @SteveBennett: yes, you can technically overwrite the entire history.  It *technically* breaks source control, but you'll "never" run into any problems in practice because anyone who clone the repository can restore history using their clone.  Plus, the preferred way to use Git is to use pull/merge requests to allow reviewing commits and so only one person has access to any given repository.

Answer (score 1):

If you force push to a repository, some commits could be unreachable as André Caron explained.

Github don't let you access the repository (because this isn't exactly a standard git repository and because this is not your business anyway). So in this case, you'll actually loose information.

But if you are the effective administrator of this repository, you're able, at some extent, to recover from a force push by browsing the reflog and then bring branches back to life.

Please note that your local repository (the one you made the force push from) should containt the to-be-losed commits and then you should be able to resurrect them if needed.

Comment: Ok - but I'm still a bit unclear. In my scenario, there is only one copy of the repository in the world, and it's on Github. So, yes, a bad force push could irrevocably lose the commits (because of the issue with getting access to the reflog)?

Comment: Technically in your scenario you have 2 repositories, the one on Github plus the one you push from.
But the fact is that your local repository may not include the state of the branch as in Github repository. So yes you'll loose commits in this very strange (but possible) state.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, some operations are going to destroy permanently your history, for example :

```
git push repo-name +master
```

will overwrite your master repo ( repo-name )  with local branch loosing master history.

But the most common way to trash your history is by interactive Rebasing:

```
git rebase -i 6bd80e12
```

... only do this on commits that haven’t been pushed an external repository. If others have based work off of the commits that you’re going to delete, plenty of conflicts can occur. Just don’t rewrite your history if it’s been shared with others.

I reccomend to read more :

http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html

http://progit.org/book/ch6-4.html

http://book.git-scm.com/4_interactive_rebasing.html

Comment: Yeah, interesting. Unlike the scenarios suggested by fred and Andre, this one could happen by mistake. You're encouraged to rewrite history, you're encouraged to share changes - you somehow have to avoid combining those two things.

Comment: @SteveBennett: Even if this happens "by mistake" (more like someone misunderstood what rebasing really does), the remote end will refuse to accept the push if it cannot perform a fast-forward merge.  There are many ways to destroy/overwrite commits.  Since all operations are done *locally*, everything is safe.  It's the `git push` that's likely to actually erase something.  You'll still need to `git push -f` to actually lose history.